# Documentation on mobile-webview.gmail.com link masking?

Tags: url-redirection, user-tracking, encoding

Several google products (mainly Gmail) [masks links using a fake-dns mobile-webview.gmail.com](https://support.google.com/business/thread/105027255/https-mobile-webview-gmail-com-876192314-8117001234026121856-m-8936162224061913563?hl=en)

That domain doesn't resolve anywhere, not even Google's own NS https://dnschecker.org/#A/mobile-webview.gmail.com

Most apps mask it in a half-broken way. Users can still long press and copy the masked, useless link, or they can click, in which case the app will change the link on the fly and send an activity to the usual google link trackers (e.g. `http://google.com/url/q=https://original.com/secret`, yep http.) which then 302 to your original link

I failed to find more information on this. How can I prevent this as the sender, or the receiver? And what are the information leaks, exploits (you can trigger a redirect from google.com via a service with non-standard url encoding *wink), etc?

Anyone know about any documentation on this? official or otherwise.